# ReadyNAS issue with Google Apps?

Tags: nas, google-workspace, smtp, readynas

The power went out (again) in my house today so I decided to set up some alerting. Since I have a ReadyNAS and the latest version of Raidinator seems to have SMTP TLS support, I figured I would try setting things up to email to a domain I have hosted on Google Apps.

At this point, I have everything working IF I use a Gmail account but as soon as I switch to a Google Apps email address, it stops working and complains with

```
smtpstatus=535 smtpmsg='535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at                   \n535 5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 30sm16076226wfd.23' errormsg='authentication failed (GNU SASL, method PLAIN)' exitcode=EX_NOPERM
```

I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this. Google's extremely aggressive captcha does not help but I am able to log in now without a captcha from a browser so I'm open to any ideas why the simple switch of a user/password combo that is *supposed* to work does not.

I'm also attaching my config so that others can see how to set things up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out:
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

I would try SSL if the mail client supports it.

I would advise against thijs recommendation to use port 25 for 2 reasons:
1) All data is sent in the clear (not so much a problem as its just you and your ISP and Google)
2) Many ISPs are starting to block port 25.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong login information from one of my Google accounts. Ensure that when you use your credentials that they are the master credentials for that Google account.

All the information above worked seamlessly.

My settings were:

```
port 587
user----username@gmail.com
Pass XXXXXXXXX
```

I changed the Login Type on my ReadyNas to login instead of Auto
and I have checked the  use Tls AND use STARTTLS boxes as well.

Answer (score 0):

set the SMTP server to aspmx.l.google.com, port 25 and don't use TLS or login

And make sure the email adress is one of the adresses on the domain wich is hosted by google.